# Unable to locate button to simulate click - Unit Testing React w/ Mocha, Chai, Enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

I'm attempting to simulate a button click with Enzyme. I've been able to write simple tests if an element renders, however the fun tests such as button clicks etc. are falling short.

In this example the error in terminal is:

```
 1) Front End @Profile Component clicks a button :
 Error: This method is only meant to be run on single node. 0 found instead.
  at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:1093:17)
  at ShallowWrapper.props (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:532:21)
  at ShallowWrapper.prop (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:732:21)
  at ShallowWrapper.simulate (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:505:28)
  at Context.<anonymous> (cmpnt-profile.spec.js:36:32)
```

the unit test is:

```
      describe('Front End @Profile Component', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<Profile/>);

     ...(other tests here)...
        it('clicks a button ', () => {

        wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
        expect(onButtonClick.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    })
});
```

the component is:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import ExpireAlert from '../components/alert';
import SocialAccount from '../components/socialAccounts'

const FIELDS = {
    name : {
        type : 'input',
        label : 'name'
    },
    username : {
        type : 'input',
        label: 'username'
    },
    email : {
        type : 'input',
        label: 'email'
    }
};

let alert = false;

export default class Profile extends Component {

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      if(nextProps.userIsUpdated){
        alert = !alert
      }
    }

    handleSubmit(userData) { // update profile
     userData.id = this.props.userInfo.id
     this.props.updateUserInfo(userData)
    }

    renderField(fieldConfig, field) { // one helper per ea field declared
      const fieldHelper = this.props.fields[field];
      return (
        <label>{fieldConfig.label}
          <fieldConfig.type type="text" placeholder={fieldConfig.label} {...fieldHelper}/>
          {fieldHelper.touched && fieldHelper.error && <div>{fieldHelper.error}</div>}
        </label>
      );
    }

  render() {
    const {resetForm, handleSubmit, submitting, initialValues} = this.props;
      return (
        <div className="login">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="small-12 large-7 large-centered columns">
              <div className="component-wrapper">
                <ExpireAlert 
                    set={this.props.userIsUpdated}
                    reset={this.props.resetAlert}
                    status="success"
                    delay={3000}>
                    <strong> That was a splendid update! </strong>
                </ExpireAlert>
                <h3>Your Profile</h3>
                <SocialAccount
                  userInfo={this.props.userInfo}
                  unlinkSocialAcc={this.props.unlinkSocialAcc}
                />
                <form className="profile-form" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))}>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="small-12 large-4 columns">
                      <img className="image" src={this.props.userInfo.img_url}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="small-12 large-8 columns">
                      {_.map(FIELDS, this.renderField.bind(this))}
                    </div>
                    <div className="small-12 columns">
                      <button type="submit" className="primary button expanded" disabled={submitting}>
                        {submitting ? <i/> : <i/>} Update
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   );
  }
}

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
     if (!values.name) {
        errors.name = 'Name is Required'
      }
      if (!values.username) {
        errors.username = 'Username is Required'
      } else if (values.username.length > 30) {
        errors.username = 'Must be 30 characters or less'
      }
      if (!values.email) {
        errors.email = 'Email is Required'
      } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Invalid email address'
      }
  return errors;
}

Profile.propTypes = {
  fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  resetForm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  submitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'Profile',
  fields: _.keys(FIELDS),
  validate
})(Profile)
```

Any suggestions appreciated. I would love to make some amazing unit tests!

Answer (score 2):

ZekeDroid is correct. Another way to handle the situation though would be to use `mount`, which is Enzyme's way to deep render components, meaning the entire tree of components are rendered. This would be considered an integration test, instead of a unit test. ZekeDroid mentions "This assumes your component can handle not receiving whatever reduxForm supplies it with, which is good practice anyhow as you will find it easier to test.", and I believe he's referencing unit testing. Ideally, your tests should include both unit tests and integration tests. I created a simple project to show how to do both unit and integration tests with redux-form. See [this repo](https://github.com/tylercollier/redux-form-test).

Answer (score 0):

You have two `export default`s on your file. This will naturally mean that the second one is overriding the first. If you really want to be able to export the `reduxForm` version and the component itself, as you should for testing, then remove the word `default` from the component.

On your test, you `shallow` render, meaning no children are rendered. Since you import the `reduxForm`, nothing much will get rendered, definitely not your `Profile`. Therefore, if you removed the `default` keyword like I mentioned, your test will start working when you import it using a named import:

```
import { Profile } from 'path/to/component';
```

*This assumes your component can handle not receiving whatever `reduxForm` supplies it with, which is good practice anyhow as you will find it easier to test.

Comment: I tried removing default from class Profile, as well as the redux form, and it resulted in some errors.  here's one from removing the export from class.

Comment: `at Parser.pp.raise (/../fairshare/divvy/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1378:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected`

Comment: ps. to clarify, I tried removing them one at a time, not both at the same time.

Comment: remove the `default` obviously not the `export`. I suggest reading the ES6 syntax notes on how to import/export: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html